# "variant" flag is deprecated and will be removed in future release. Please switch to "mode" flag

Tags: android, react-native

when i run this command `npx react-native run-android --variant="release"` in cmd to run the react-native project in cmd in release varaint it says

"variant" flag is deprecated and will be removed in future release. Please switch to "mode" flag.

Comment: What happens when you do `npx react-native run-android --mode="release"`

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is switch from `debug` to `release` then you can use the `--mode` flag:

```
npx react-native run-android --mode=release
```

But if you have other build variants then that won't suffice. Instead you can [use the `--tasks` flag](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/a9885acc91f3a751d592c849b503c52c0105a9c0/packages/cli-platform-android/README.md#--tasks-list):

```
npx react-native run-android --tasks installStagingDebug
```

This is equivalent to `--variant stagingDebug`, where `install` is the Gradle command, `staging` is the product flavour and `debug` is the build type.